# Python error while connecting to nntp server

Tags: python, nntp

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    server = NNTP('http://www.news.readfreenews.net')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\nntplib.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
>>>
```

Can you Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using HTTP to connect to NNTP? Replace `server = NNTP('http://www.news.readfreenews.net')` with `server = NNTP('news.readfreenews.net')` or `server = NNTP('www.news.readfreenews.net')`, depending on which works fine.

Comment: www.news.readfreenews.net is supposed to get you this error, because there's no such host (try pinging it). However, news.readfreenews.net shouldn't cause any error.